# JMeter Reponse Assertion lower case value

Tags: javascript, jmeter

In the response assertion, I have in patterns to test this value.

```
"isDefault":false,"companyId":"${__javaScript(${Company}.toLowerCase())}","folderPath":null
```

I do not want to change the value of the variable ${Company}, I just want to check if what I receive is in lower case.

This is the assertion result:

> Assertion error: false Assertion failure: true Assertion failure
>   message: Test failed: text expected to contain
>   /"isDefault":false,"companyId":"","folderPath":null/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your `${Company}` variable reference with quotation marks like:

```
"isDefault":false,"companyId":"${__javaScript("${Company}".toLowerCase(),)}","folderPath":null
```

---

Be aware that using __javaScript() function is not very recommended as JavaScript interpreter performance can be a big question mark when it comes to high loads so consider following alternative approaches:

1. Use [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function which is [recommended approach to scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

   ```
   "isDefault":false,"companyId":"${__groovy(vars.get("Company").toLowerCase(),)}","folderPath":null
   ```
2. Use [__lowerCase() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#uppercase-and-lowercasesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) (this is not a part of official JMeter distribution, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

   ```
   isDefault":false,"companyId":"${__lowercase(${Company},)}","folderPath":null
   ```

Demo for all approaches:

[image: JMeter LowerCase Convert Variable]